# Conversion of DOM element selection code to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, selection

I have a large Javascript codebase to convert to jQuery.  The code is structured such that DOM elements are created in Javascript (using a library called DomBuilder), and saved to variables if they will be needed later, before being added to the DOM.

Eg.

```
var inputs =
{
    submitConfirm: INPUT({type: 'button', value: 'Submit'}),
    submitCancel : INPUT({type: 'button', value: 'Cancel'})
};

document.appendChild(inputs.submitConfirm);
```

Then later for example...

```
inputs.submitCancel.style.display = 'none';
inputs.submitCancel.addEventListener('click', onClickSubmitCancel, false);
```

My problem is that jQuery seems to lack a way of manipulating DOM elements directly, as opposed to selecting them first (with for example $('#submitCancel').

Can anyone suggest a way to directly translate the last two Javascript lines given above to use jQuery, given that the DOM elements are already available, and so do not need to be selected?

Comment: Out of curiosity: Why would one want to add a heavy-weight framework to a finished, working script?

Comment: For cross-browser compatibility.  The code currently only works on Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any DOM element can be wrapped into a jQuery object very easily:

```
var myObject = $(domElement)
```

With myObject you can use jQuery methods.

Comment: Ah!  Simple!  My conversion project will be as straightforward as I had hoped.  Thank you all for your prompt responses.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(inputs.submitCancel).css('display', 'none');
```

and

```
$(inputs.submitCancel).bind('click', onClickSubmitCancel);
```

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/ to see what jQuery accepts.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(elementVar)` to get a jQuery object containing the DOM element. For the example you gave:

```
$(inputs.submitCancel).hide().click(onClickSubmitCancel);
```